# Migrate Enterprise Architect settings

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is there any way to move Enterprise Architect settings from one installation to another? I have several projects on my old computer set up and I would like to move them to a new computer without having to set everything up again (e.g. SVN setup etc..). I am using EA 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve this by exporting and importing registry data in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sparx Systems` and also copying the whole folder in: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Sparx Systems`